# `pd.read_sql(sql, engine)` raises NotImplementedError: This method is not implemented for SQLAlchemy 2.0

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, read-sql

I tried to create a pandas DataFrame directly from my sqlserver database using an sqlalchemy engine:

```
engine = create_engine(URL_string, echo=False, future=True)
query_string = "..."
dt = pd.read_sql(query_string, engine)
```

But this raises this error:

```
File <redacted>/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/future/engine.py:320, in Engine._not_implemented(self, *arg, **kw)
    319 def _not_implemented(self, *arg, **kw):
--> 320     raise NotImplementedError(
    321         "This method is not implemented for SQLAlchemy 2.0."
    322     )

NotImplementedError: This method is not implemented for SQLAlchemy 2.0.
```

I do this because using pyodbc's connection alone gives a warning:

```
UserWarning: pandas only support SQLAlchemy connectable(engine/connection) ordatabase string URI or sqlite3 DBAPI2 connectionother DBAPI2 objects are not tested, please consider using SQLAlchemy
  warnings.warn(
```

I'm using sqlalchemy version 1.4 ... so how do I fix this?

Comment: This can maybe answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77486972/5506438

Answer (score 4):

Just remove `future=True` from the `engine` parameters:

```
engine = create_engine(URL_string, echo=False)
```

Then you should be good to go!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me to use pyodbc and pandas cohesively. Just replace the query and connection info.

```
import pandas as pd
import warnings

query = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE'
conn = pyodbc.connect('db connection info')

with warnings.catch_warnings():
     warnings.simplefilter('ignore', UserWarning)
     df = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this looks to be an open issue that won't be solved till pandas 2.0, you can find some information about this [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/44794) and [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/44823#issuecomment-993828292).

I didn't find any satisfactory work around, but some people seems to be using two configurations of the engine, one with the flag future False:

```
engine2 = create_engine(URL_string, echo=False, future=False)
```

This solution would be ok if you make query strings as you did, but if you are using the ORM for me the best I could do is a custom function, that is probably far from optimal, but works:

```
Conditions = session.query(ExampleTable)
def custom_read(query):
    return pd.DataFrame([i.__dict__ for i in query]).drop(columns='_sa_instance_state')
df = custom_read(ExampleTable)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, the easiest way to get access to the `execute` function is through an `engine.connect()` context manager. You also need to use the `text` function since the execute function no longer accepts raw strings.

This is what worked for me:

```py
from sqlalchemy import text

with engine.connect() as connection:
    dt= pd.read_sql_query(text(query_string), conn)
```

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#basic-usage