# Passing a non-executable SQL object to pandas read_sql() method

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I'm facing this new warning within some Python 3.9 code:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py:761:
  UserWarning:
    pandas only support SQLAlchemy connectable(engine/connection) or
    database string URI or sqlite3 DBAPI2 connectionother DBAPI2
    objects are not tested, please consider using SQLAlchemy
```

on such snippet:

```
import pandas as pd
from psycopg2 import sql

fields = ('object', 'category', 'number', 'mode')

query = sql.SQL("SELECT {} FROM categories;").format(
    sql.SQL(', ').join(map(sql.Identifier, fields))
)

df = pd.read_sql(
    sql=query,
    con=connector() # custom function which returns db parameters as a psycopg2 connection object
)
```

It works like a charm for the moment, but according to the warning message, I'd like to switch to SQLAlchemy.

But by doing so:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://', creator=connector)

df = pd.read_sql(
    sql=query,
    con=engine
)
```

it says:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ObjectNotExecutableError: Not an executable object:
  Composed([SQL('SELECT '), Composed([Identifier('object'), SQL(', '),
  Identifier('category'), SQL(', '), Identifier('number'), SQL(', '),
  Identifier('mode')]), SQL(' FROM categories;')])
```

So I have to tweak it this way to avoid this error:

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://', creator=connector)

conn = connector()
curs = conn.cursor()

df = pd.read_sql(
    sql=query.as_string(conn), # non-pythonic, isn't it?
    con=engine
)
```

I'm wondering what's the benefit of using an SQLAlchemy engine with pandas if I have to "decode" the query string using a psycpg2 connection context... (in some specific cases where the query string is a binary string I have to "decode" it by applying `.decode('UTF-8')`...)

How can I rewrite the DataFrame construction in a *proper* (i.e. the *best*) way by using an SQLAlchemy engine with pandas?

The pandas [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) is not 100% clear for me:

> Parameters
>
> ```
> sqlstr or SQLAlchemy Selectable (select or text object)
>
>     SQL query to be executed or a table name.
> ```

Version info:

python: 3.9
pandas: '1.4.3'
sqlalchemy: '1.4.35'
psycopg2: '2.9.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)'

Answer (score 2):

The query can be expressed in SQLAlchemy syntax like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa

fields = ('object', 'category', 'number', 'mode')

# Adjust engine configuration to match your environment.
engine = sa.create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2:///test')
metadata = sa.MetaData()

# Reflect the table from the database.
tbl = sa.Table('categories', metadata, autoload_with=engine)

# Get column objects for column names.
columns = [tbl.c[name] for name in fields]

query = sa.select(*columns)

df = pd.read_sql(sql=query, con=engine)
print(df)
```

Comment: This just reads from a single table. What if you want to run a query with multiple joins?

Comment: @ziggy it would be the same in principle, except you would have to apply `.join_from` to the `select`.

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas v.2.1.2 and SQLAlchemy >= 2.0.22

You can use psycopg2 syntax for parameters and the "native" strsql string.

```py
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://...')
strsql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = %(myid)s;"
params = {"myid": 1}
df = pd.DataFrame()
with engine.connect() as db_connection:
    df = pd.read_sql(
        sql=strsql,
        con=db_connection,
        params=params,
    )
```

Using pandas v 1.5.3 and SQLAlchemy >= 2.0.22

Here you have a workaround to do the same thing. In short, you have to use the text() function of SQLAlchemy and use the SQLAlchemy syntax for parameters.

```py
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text

engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://...')
strsql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = :myid;"
params = {"myid": 1}
df = pd.DataFrame()
with engine.connect() as db_connection:
    df = pd.read_sql(
        sql=text(strsql),
        con=db_connection,
        params=params,
    )
```